# How to listen what SoapClient sends to server during request?

Tags: php, soap, request

I'm trying to debug a PHP script that sends request to server via SOAP. I have to insert a structured variable into SOAP request message but I'm getting errors with rather unhelpful fault messages like "string" :/

So I'd like to check the raw request sent by SoapClient class to server. By "raw" I meant I need XML string being passed. Like 
`<soapenv:Envelope ...>...<myVar>...</myVar>...</soapenv:Envelope>`.

How do I do that? I run the script on Debian host so I tried looking at netcat but I cannot find something suitable among the options list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, I think the "rawest" one would be to trace/view the network traffic with a tool like Wireshark.

Please take a look at  https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/AppToolstcpdump.html where is described how to trace the network traffic on a linux system and store it into a file which you can open with wireshark and analize the network traffic.

If I've remembered it correctly, this only works flawless if you have an unsecured connection between the two hosts.

**Edit**

If you are only interested in the requests XML the php SOAP client has a method "__getLastRequest" http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php

Comment: Oh, sorry, this "raw" was not precise. I meant I need XML string being passed. Like <soapenv:Envelope ...>...<myVar>...</myVar>...</soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: @Forseti You can get the XML string with this method too, just inspect the package contents (i think there is even an option whick shows you the complete content/body for a single tcp session)

Comment: __getLastRequest() was the way to go. Simplest and working. Thanks!